# Unanswered questions should not appear at "Questions that may already have your answer"

Tags: feature-request, user-interface, unanswered-questions

I was just asking the 3rd ever question on a new private beta, and the existing 2 questions (with 1 view, 0 comments, 0 answers) both appeared in the "Questions that may already have your answer" box.  They can't possibly have my answer, because *they don't have any answer*.

The box "Questions that may already have your answer" should not contain any unanswered questions.

Comment: There are questions that are unanswered but do have comments/answers that might have the answer you are looking for.

Comment: Good point, a question can indeed contain an answer, I was thinking quite literally in the Q&A sense...  so perhaps it's not a bug as such.  It's still worth thinking about, though.

Comment: Maybe if it is 0 comments and questions it doesn't show, but if it has at least one answer then it should. I think that would be at least a bit better.

Comment: @Howlin comments are not answers... they are comments. That an answer might be in a comment shouldn't apply.

Answer (score 2):

The label for it is a little misleading, but those questions ***should*** still appear.

The main reason I see for this feature is to prevent duplicates. If you have a near identical title, it'll quickly get picked up and then a possible duplicate might be prevented.

Chances are, if it's not answered, it's probably not possible (someone sometimes leaves a comment). If it is possible, that means that either nobody cares about it enough to put in the effort or it's not getting enough views. If it's possible but not getting enough attention, try adding a bounty to the existing question.

And there is a way that you can tell if it has any answers; a little number appears after each link. (If there are no answers, nothing will appear).

> [image]

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that when **at least one answer or comment** has been given by any user, it should appear in that list.

That one answer, maybe not marked as **the answer** can still be the answer I was looking for preventing me from creating almost a duplicate question.

*Doing a quick-check resulted in the result I was expecting and I've put above this line.*